# High Current Power Supply Design

Tags: power-supply, design, high-current

I'm looking to design a high current low voltage power supply that goes beyond my limited circuit knowledge. I have plenty of experience putting circuits together, but not so much on the design side.

## What I Want

**Input:** 120v AC at 60Hz (US Wall outlet)

**Output:** 3.7V (I can deal with 4 if that makes a difference) up to 10A DC. The loads are going to be small, less than 2 Ohm.

I could probably hack this together with a transformer, full wave bridge and a capacitor but here's the part I'm having trouble with: I want 4 outputs that can be, but aren't necessarily, all operating simultaneously.

## My Thoughts

The output would be easy enough to wire 4 outputs in parallel to meet the same 3.7v/10A requirement for a total current of 40A if I understand correctly. What I'm not sure about is being able to run, for instance, 2 of the 4, and not get 3.7v and 20A in each. So some way to limit the current in each line is needed.

Generally, I'm lost apart from the simple circuit I described above. Any direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If each load is around 2 ohms then a 10 amp supply is more than adequate.
Each load will only draw the amps it requires based on its own resistance
and Ohms law.

Comment: 3.7V and 2 ohm = 1.85A. Multiply this by 4 and you get 7.4A. How you conclude that you might need 40A eludes me.

Comment: @Andyaka After thinking about it more, I realized I left out probably the more important part of this - I really want constant power output of around 30-40W, which is where the high current comes from. On the low end, the loads will be around 0.5 Ohm which is the high end of the current I've described above.

Comment: Sounds like this is going to be the vaping version of a hookah .... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will keep this easy and simple. Use buck converters to create your low voltage. You can buy them easily if you are in a hurry. Keep the outputs close to your loads so you do not have to worry about voltage drop along a cable. The buck converters that you buy might be happy on say 12V input which is common in computers. You can just buy a PC power supply to get the 12V if you are in a hurry.

If you do decide to use a transformer, bridge rectifier, and filter cap it will now be easy because the voltage does not need to be exactly 12 and the buck converters will happily attenuate any ripple from your rectified filtered DC. In other words the filter cap does not have to be too huge. If you don't buck down you will need an oddball transformer with enormous filter caps and big diodes only to get rewarded with poor voltage regulation under line and load changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, someone else suggested buck converters as well so I'll look into them!